# Не читается параметр self в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется функция которая принимает параметр self, но код принимает ее за аргумент который надо передавать, почему так?

запрос к функции:

```
lobby = LobbyFiender.Lobby.SearchGameRequest(
        accountDates.lvl, accountDates.name)
```

функция:

```
def SearchGameRequest(self, lvl, nick):
    accountDates = User(session['login'], session['password'], session['nick'])
    cursor.execute(
        "SELECT id FROM lobby WHERE lvl = ? AND pCount < 10 AND status = 'waiting players' LIMIT 1", [accountDates.lvl])
    if cursor.fetchone():
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        Lobby.AddPlayersToLobby(nick)

        self.id = data[0]
        self.status = data[1]
        self.type = data[2]
        self.map = data[3]
        self.lvl = data[4]
        self.pCount = data[5]
        self.AcceptedPlayersCount = data[6]
        self.players = {
            'p1': data[7],
            'p2': data[8],
            'p3': data[9],
            'p4': data[10],
            'p5': data[11],
            'p6': data[12],
            'p7': data[13],
            'p8': data[14],
            'p9': data[15],
            'p10': data[16]
        }
        self.CanselGameVoting = data[17]
```

Comment: Потому что `self` - это ссылка на экземпляр класса. Видимо, у вас должен быть в наличии экземпляр класса `Lobby`, тогда вы сможете вызвать у него этот метод.